# Change the status automatically after the add of a revision

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 forms, the first is the form `motorbikes` with 3 fields (matriculation, number_motorbike, status).

[image]

Then, we have the form `revisions` with 4 fields (date_revision_start, date_revision_end, garage, fk_motorbike)

[image]

Here in the form `motorbikes` the status of the number motorbike must to be automatically `unavailable`.

[image]

I must to work on which controller to automate the availability status of the motorbike?

Edit: **09 / 07 / 2018**

Controller Motorbike

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {      

       $bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<", Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">", Carbon::now())->pluck('id')->toArray();

       return view('motorbikes.index', compact('motorbikes', 'bikeIdsDown'));

        }
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($motorbikes as $bike)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $bike->martriculation }}</td>
            <td>{{ $bike->number_motorbike }}</td>
            <td>
             @if(in_array($bike->id, $bikeIdsDown))
              UNAVAILABLE
              @else
              Available
            @endif</td>
            <td>
                          <form action="{{ route('motorbikes.destroy', $motorbike->id) }}" method="post">

                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
                            <a href="{{ url('motorbike/' .$motorbike->id. '/edit') }}" class="btn btn-warning">Editer</a>
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
                        </form>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the list of motorbikes that are unavailable, you would need to work on your **Motorbike Controller**.  Specifically, the `edit()` method if you are making changes to the status manually, the `create()` method if you are making a new motorbike, or most likely, the `show()` method to just display that table you have above where it shows if they are available or not.

Now... to get the part where it displays if the bike is unavailable... I assume it is unavailable when it is down for repair (revision).  Since I don't know what your relations are, we can figure this out using a simple pull from all revisions to see which bikes should be down currently.  So, in one of those methods I noted above (or all of them), first let's see which bikes are down for revision, during the current time:

```
$bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<" Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">", Carbon::now())->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Not the most efficient, but simplest to follow hopefully.

Now that we have these unavailable motorbike ids, if we compact them and send them through to the blade page, we can determine whether to write 'available or 'unavailable' in the motorbike field.  So, as you are looping through the motorbikes on the blade page, maybe something like this:

```
@foreach($motorbikes as $bike) 
    {{$bike->martriculation }}  // <-- these might all be in <td> or something
    {{$bike->number}}
    @if(in_array($bike->id, $bikeIdsDown))
        UNAVAILABLE
    @else
        Available
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Hopefully this will give you the idea.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your informative explanations. So I have to use carbon?

Comment: Don't have to, you can use DB::raw with the SQL command... but Carbon is already in Laravel as part of its core package, and it makes it a little easier, so pretty helpful.

Comment: It seems that the ligne 74 `$bikeIdsDown = Revision::where('date_revision_start', "<" Carbon::now())->where('date_revision_end', ">", Carbon::now())->pluck('id')->toArray();` is incorrect "syntax error, unexpected 'Carbon' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'" it s a problem of sytnhax?

Comment: Shoot.  Sorry - I wrote that in SO, not with an IDE, so I didn't see my mistake.  I missed a comma in the standard formatting for a Laravel where clause.  Add a comma right after the operator in the first where clause.  Should be:  `where('date_revision_start', "<", Carbon::now())` and then the rest

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand why in my file index.blade.php I have as error message Undefined variable: bikeIdsDown.. For information, I have edited my first message. I'm lost... :-(

Comment: Don't forget to send the variable through to the blade file.  So whatever method is sending to that table (maybe index?  show? - make sure you put the code in to get your list of `$bikeIdsDown` in that method, then compact the `$bikeIdsDown` variable just like you would with `$motorbikes`.  So:  `return view('motorbikes.index', compact('motorbikes', 'bikeIdsDown'))`.  You need to create the list, then send it through to the blade view using compact.